# Maya Python: fix matching names

Tags: python, nodes, maya

I am writing a script to export alembic caches of animation in a massive project containing lots of maya files. Our main character is having an issue; along the way his eyes somehow ended up with the same name. This has created issues with the alembic export. Dose maya already have a sort of clean up function that can correct matching names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any two objects can have the same names, but never the same DAG paths. In your script, make sure all your ls, listRelatives calls etc. Have the full path or longName or long flags set so you always operate on the full DAG paths as opposed to the possibly conflicting short names.

Comment: Thanks! That was a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge maya (and its python api) does not offer anything like that.

You'll have to run a snippet on export to check for duplicates before export. 
Or, alternatively use an [already existing](http://www.riganimator.com/script-test/) script and run that.

Comment: Thanks J4ck, ill check it out!